# VS Code Quick File Navigation not working for custom file system provider

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've written a custom FileSystemProvider for VS Code.
When I open the files/folder with my custom FileSystemProvider's schema it works as expected and the files are shown in the workspace explorer.
But even though the files/folders are listed in workspace the following options of vs code are not working anymore for the custom file provider

1. Quick File Navigation (Ctrl + P) is unable to find the files in my workspace provided by custom FileSystemProvider
2. Find/Replace - Find replace is also unable to find the contents from the files in the workspace provided by custom FileSystemProvider
3. Find Symbols/ Declaration/ Definition are also not working

Is there a way to register my custom FileSystemProvider's schema also to these tools?

Remark : My custom FileSystemProvider directly uses the files in the local disc and it uses vscode.workspace.fs to read directories and files from the disc. It just hides few files and directories provided from the disc.

Comment: I already tried to register my schema with "registerTextDocumentContentProvider". But it does no help

Answer (score 0):

This is already known and there is an proposed VS Code API FileSearchProvider available to fix this.
The API is planed to be stabilized in [Stabilize FileSearchProvider API #73524](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/73524)